# Get Entity Table Name - EF7

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

As the question states, anyone know how to get the entity table name in entity framework 7?

I have the code to do this in entity framework 6.1 (from another site, cant find link), but none of the interfaces/objects seem to be referenced in entity framework 7.

Code for EF6.1

```
public string GetTableName(Type type)
{
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    var objectItemCollection = ((ObjectItemCollection)metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));
    var entityType = metadata.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace).Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == type);
    var entitySet = metadata.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace).Where(x => x.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType).Cast<EntityType>().Single(x => x.Name == entityType.Name);
    var entitySetMappings = metadata.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace).Single().EntitySetMappings.ToList();

    EntitySet table = null;

    var mapping = entitySetMappings.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EntitySet.Name == entitySet.Name);
    if (mapping != null)
    {
        table = mapping.EntityTypeMappings.Single().Fragments.Single().StoreEntitySet;
    }
    else
    {
        mapping = entitySetMappings.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EntityTypeMappings.Where(y => y.EntityType != null).Any(y => y.EntityType.Name == entitySet.Name));

        if (mapping != null)
        {
            table = mapping.EntityTypeMappings.Where(x => x.EntityType != null).Single(x => x.EntityType.Name == entityType.Name).Fragments.Single().StoreEntitySet;
        }
        else
        {
            var entitySetMapping = entitySetMappings.Single(x => x.EntityTypeMappings.Any(y => y.IsOfEntityTypes.Any(z => z.Name == entitySet.Name)));
            table = entitySetMapping.EntityTypeMappings.First(x => x.IsOfEntityTypes.Any(y => y.Name == entitySet.Name)).Fragments.Single().StoreEntitySet;
        }
    }

    return (string)table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value ?? table.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only thing you need to do now to achieve the same is this:

```
public string GetTableName(Type type)
{
   return this.Model.GetEntityType(type).SqlServer().TableName;
}
```

PS: I'm assuming this method is declared in your `DbContext` class, otherwise change the `this` keyword for your `DbContext` instance.

### Update

`GetEntityType` was renamed to `FindEntityType`. You can find more info in this [link](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2016/11/09/ef-core-1-1-metadata-overview/)

```
return this.Model.FindEntityType(type).SqlServer().TableName;
```

Comment: Will try this later when i am at a machine but if this works (sure it will) that is awesome!!

Comment: Doesnt seem to compile.  I have no such method ```.Relational```

Comment: Did you add the [EntityFramework.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Relational/) reference?

Comment: I have just added it, and nothing.  Even added ```using Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational;``` and still nothing?

Comment: Now I create a new project using the latest release (beta 7) and you're right, it has changed.  You need to use now `SqlServer`  extension method instead `Relational`. I guess the EF team is changing that due to they want each EF provider implements its own way how to expose metadata

Comment: `GetEntityType` did not exist for me. This worked, though: `_db.Model.FindEntityType( type ).SqlServer().TableName;` Perhaps they renamed it.

Comment: Probably should be that, I will take a look later, thanks for the feedback ;)